# How to mantain View across document libraries

Tags: list-view, view

I had a custom list which has some Custom Views created..
If I go and modify a View by Web Interface in List1, List2 doesn't show that modify.. Is there any way to do this?

In event handler I cannot listen to "view modify" or something like that..

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Views are per list instance, not list type, even if they can be defined in custom list schema. You can't change a view and propogate the changes out-of-the-box. You'll have to code or script the changes if you want to automate it.

Comment: I believe a view is specific to a list/library, not sure if there is a way to share the same view across different list. If you do find the answer let me know? I'm also curious to know if there is a way. =)